# О союзах ТОЖЕ и ТАКЖЕ

Tags: союзы

Вопросы:

1) **Какая это часть речи**

В учебнике по морфологии ТОЖЕ, ТАКЖЕ включены  в две группы сочинительных союзов: **соединительные и присоединительные.** В толковом словаре говорится о присоединительном союзе ТАКЖЕ и о наречии ТОЖЕ.

2)  **А что в них присоединительного (добавочного по смыслу)?** Они скорее обозначают соответствие ситуаций, а не дополнительную информацию.

3) Может быть, ТОЖЕ, ТАКЖЕ являются присоединительными союзами, **когда всё предложение присоединительное**: **Я тоже промолчал.** Или это наречие? **Также не стоит пренебрегать их советами.** Это присоединительный союз?

4) Считается, что ТОЖЕ, ТАКЖЕ **можно заменить союзом И,** кроме того, они могут замещать друг друга. Но это возможно не в любом предложении, и тогда возникает вопрос **о семантических особенностях каждого союза.**

а) Можно заменить: **Он согласен, мы тоже/также не возражаем. Он согласен, и мы  не возражаем.**

б) Нельзя заменить? **Я перестал спрашивать, все тоже/также приумолкли.**  Союз И не подходит, а из двух союзов какой лучше выбрать? Вроде бы ТОЖЕ подходит больше. Влияют ли исходные местоимения ТО(ЖЕ), ТАК(ЖЕ) на значение союзов?

**Из словаря**

**ТАКЖЕ,** союз. Присоединяет однородные члены предложения или предложения в составе сложного. Он согласен, мы т. не возражаем.

**ТОЖЕ.** I. нареч. Равным образом, в равной мере; также. Он устал, я т. Одежда грязная, обувь т. Я перестал спрашивать, все т. приумолкли.